# What's the difference between these 2 declarations in c?

Tags: c, syntax

```
typedef int (*P)(char *(*)());

int (*P)(char *(*)());
```

Both seems to be doing the same thing to me,what's the `typedef` there for?

Answer (score 9):

The first declares a *type* called P that you can use in the declaration of other variables.  The second declares a *variable* of that same type.

For illustrative purposes:

```
typedef int (*P)(char *(*)());

int main() {
    int (*Q)(char *(*)());
    P R;
}
```

In this example the variables `Q` and `R` have exactly the same type.

Comment: You are on fire mate! 945 rep in 4 days! +1

Comment: Haha, thanks.  Yeah... I should probably, you know, go outside for some fresh air soon.

Comment: That fresh air is overrated :D

Comment: So are sunlight and exercise... two of my least favorite things!

Answer (score 4):

The `typedef` defines `P` to be a function pointer *type*.  The second version defines `P` to be a function pointer.

A type can be used to declare variables.  After

```
typedef int (*P)(char *(*)());
```

you can use

```
P p;
```

which will be equivalent to

```
int (*p)(char *(*)());
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer would be you are creating a new datatype through typedef.

Let's take a simple example, in embedded system we use only unsigned numbers. 
Now 1 way is I write

```
unsigned int xyz;
```

So here I would have to type unsigned everywhere.. What if I forget to type unsigned somewhere, it's very difficult to figure out that if the code is released. So simple way would be

```
typedef unsigned int uint;
```

So now you can use uint as a datatype. So whenever parser encounter uint, it would read it as unsigned int.

So in your case you can use P as a datatype in code. So Like in the first example

```
P xyz ;
```

would be parsed as

```
int (*xyz)(char *(*)());
```